# Send an application to a specific Space

Tags: spaces

Is there a way to send the current used application to a specific Space?

For example, I work in Space 1; I double-click on a document and an application starts to open this document. Is there a quick way to send this application to Space 2?

Comment: One option would be to use SizeUp to assign shortcuts for moving the focused window to the next or previous space. See [How to move a window to another space without using the mouse?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1488/how-to-move-a-window-to-another-space-without-using-the-mouse).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a particular kayboard shortcut you can use, but if you click on the app's title bar and hold mouse button and then click <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> where <kbd>n</kbd> is the number of the screen you want to send it to it will be moved there. Bear in mind you will be moved there too.

Comment: Super nice ! That's what I was looking for ! Thanks

Comment: Looks like cmd + n works for me in Lion.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to always use the same Space for an application, then you can assign it from the "Esposé and Spaces" preference panel.  "Every spaces" allows you to see the windows of that application in every spaces, independently  from the space where you opened that application.

[image: screenshot]

If you want to move an application window from a Space to another, then click on the Spaces icon shown in the dock, and Spaces will show you all the available spaces; from that screen you can move a window between spaces.